# Use 3D rotation on 3D rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, 3d, rotations

I have a $3D$ rotation matrix $(3,3)$:

[image]

and I want to apply a rotation to this matrix which is represented by another $R$ matrix. How can I do that?

Comment: ....matrix multiplication?

Comment: Make sure you get the order correct! 3D rotations (& matrix multiplication) are generally not commutative.

Comment: You dont "apply a rotation to a matrix". You either have a matrix that represents active rotations of points in a fixed coordinate system, or you have a matrix that represents a passive rotation (i.e. changes of coordinate systems with fixed points). Once this is sorted out, using a (correctly ordered) matrix product gives the answer.